# $\phi=(\phi_2,..\phi_n): \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n-1}} $ is a $C^2$ function show that det is zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $\phi=(\phi_2,..\phi_n): \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{n-1}} $ is a $C^2$ function i.e all second order partial derivatives of the $\phi_i$ exists and continuous . Show that symbolic determinant 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}       & \frac{\partial\phi_2 }{\partial x_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial \phi_n }{\partial x_1}  \\
     \\
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x_n}       & \frac{\partial\phi_2 }{\partial x_n} & \dots & \frac{\partial \phi_n }{\partial x_n}  \
\end{bmatrix}

vanishes identically .

I really don't have any great idea to start with but i guess this has to do with mixed partial derivatives .
Anyway a complete is well appreciated .

Comment: How is $\phi$ a function to $\Bbb R^{n-1}$? Is it on purpose that $\phi_1$ does not occur in the atrix?

Comment: What is ${\partial\over\partial x_i}$ supposed do to in that determinant? All the $\phi_j$ partials obviously are functions, but the former is an operator.

Comment: @Hagen : See the edit . I hope that clarifies everything .

Comment: @Adam : If i understand correctly , then yes it is supposed to be an operator . That is the reason why the word "symbolic" is mentioned in question .

Comment: That determinant is an operator, it takes the function $\phi_1$ and evaluate the determinant and it gives a function . right?

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geqslant 2$, let $D_n$ be the given determinant and use induction to prove it vanishes.

- For $n=2$, one has:
  $$D_2={\partial^2}_{x_1x_2}\phi_2-{\partial^2}_{x_2x_1}\phi_2,$$
  which is zero using Schwarz equality for $C^2$ functions.
- Assume that $n\geqslant 3$ and that the result holds for $D_{n-1}$, then conclude expanding $D_n$ with respect with its last column.